# Words that change meaning when the first letter is capitalized

Tags: meaning, capitalization

What words change meaning when the first letter is capitalised? The only word with this property that comes to mind is *polish*/*Polish* (the pronunciation also changes in this case, but that's not a necessity part of what I'm asking for).

Comment: Looks like there's a name for these types of words. Capitonym, check out the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym

Comment: I thought what made it different was not that the meaning changed, but that the pronounciation changed: Polish and polish are pronounced differently.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't think of any other word that changes its meaning so completely. Most often, a word changes because a noun becomes a proper noun, usually either a brand or a place where something commonly known originated. The Polish/polish pair is different; the proper noun (adjective actually) has nothing to do with the common noun.

For instance:

- "china", uncapitalized, is a plate. "China", capitalized, is a country.
- "comet" is an astronomical object. "Comet" is a cleaning powder.
- "burgundy" is a color, and a wine of that color. "Burgundy" is the French region that produces the wine.
- Similarly, "cheddar" is a cheese, and "Cheddar" is an English city where the cheese became known.
- A "jack" lifts cars up, but if a "Jack" can do that I wouldn't want to fight him.
- "coke" is most properly the term for a fuel product made from destructive distillation of coal via high heat. "Coke" is the well-known synonym for Coca-Cola, which gets its name from the original (but LONG since discontinued) use of coca leaf extracts (i.e. cocaine) in the drink.
- Here's a Polish/polish one: turkey's the bird, while Turkey's the country. I originally thought they had nothing to do with each other, but it seems that the bird was introduced to Europe through the country.
- Most other nationalities were careful enough to encourage different Latin spellings of their names versus the common nouns that are homonymous, but a listener still has to check for context to know whether a person is speaking of Finns, Czechs and Kurds, and not fins, checks and curds.

EDIT: For posterity, the term for these words is "[Capitonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym)".

Comment: Cheddar is a [village](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheddar) rather than a city :)

Comment: Actually "turkey" the fowl is related to "Turkey" the country: The name originated because these creatures were imported to Europe via Turkey.

Comment: I did not know that; editing.

Comment: "I can't think of any other word that changes its meaning so completely." Well, *March* and *May* would be two examples off the top of my head. Actually, *August* as well.