# Are there words that are spelled the same but pronounced differently depending on whether the initial letter is capital or lowercase?

Tags: capitalization, pronunciation-vs-spelling

There are some pairs of words that are spelled the same, aside from capitalization, but pronounced differently. One example of this is *Polish - polish.*
I remembered another pair but forgot it. Can somebody help?

The following question is related, but not the same because it only asks about words with different meanings, and doesn't specify that they must have different pronunciations: "[Words that change meaning when the first letter is capitalized](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33948)"

Comment: You specify capitals being import in the question title but neither answer has addressed capitals specifically. Is that an important part of the question?

Comment: My [Chance card](http://cdbpdx.com/MONOPOLY_1936/MONOPOLY_c1937_Chance_RideTheReading.JPG) says, "Take a ride on the Reading. If you pass Go, collect $200."

Comment: Surely the capitalisation _itself_ isn't what determines the difference in pronunciation, it's because they're different words (one of which is usually a proper noun).  "_Polish people often think of Warsaw_" vs. "_Polish this brass ornament!_"

Comment: How do you pronounce it then?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question. Yes.

Comment: @sumelic: The poster here is asking for words whose pronunciation is different as a proper name and as a common word—like _Polish/polish_ and J.R.'s example _Reading [Pennsylvania]/reading_.  That isn't a duplicate of the question about words that change meaning between proper name and common name, although any proper name is likely to have a different meaning from that of a common word that has the same spelling.

Comment: One odd case is _Lima/lima_: The capital of Peru is usually pronounced _leemuh_ in English, but (as I understand it) _Lima_, Ohio, is pronounced like the _lima_ in _lima bean_.

Answer (score 33):

There are more than two actually.

Here's a list of **twelve** heteronym pairs in which one word is capitalized (typically, a proper noun), and the other is not:

- August /ˈɔːgəst/ (proper noun) and august /ɔːˈgʌst/ (adjective)
- Begin /(the Israeli politician) and begin /bɪˈɡɪn/ (to start)
- Degas /deɪɡɑː/ and degas /diːˈɡæs/
- Job /dʒoʊb/ (the Biblical figure) and job /dʒɒb/ (an occupation)
- Natal /nəˈtɑːl, -ˈtæl/ (the Brazilian city) and natal /ˈneɪtəl/
- Nice /niːs/ (the city in France) and nice /naɪs/ (kind, friendly)
- Noel /ˈnoʊəl/ (name) and noel /noʊˈɛl/ (a Christmas carol)
- Polish /ˈpoʊlɪʃ/ (the nationality) and polish /ˈpɒlɪʃ/ (making things shiny)
- Rainier /rəˈnɪər, reɪˈnɪər/ (the name, or mountain) and rainier /ˈreɪniər/ (more rainy)
- Reading /ˈrɛdɪŋ/ (the place name) and reading /ˈriːdɪŋ/ (the activity involving books)
- SEAT /ˈsɛ.æt/ (the Spanish automaker) and seat /siːt/
- Tangier /tænˈdʒɪər/ (in Morocco) and tangier /ˈtæŋiər/ (more tangy)

– words taken from [Richard Stevens's List of Heteronyms](http://richard.tangle-wood.co.uk/heteronym.html)

***Scone/scone*** and ***Lima/lima*** can be added to the list.

Comment: This would appear to be the only answer so far that answers the question, specifically that it refers to initial capitalisation. +1.

Comment: Which ones are pronounced differently, if you label the ones that have a different pronunciation it's +1 from me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - aren't they all ?  Isn't that the point?

Comment: @Dan how is *Job* pronounced differently from *job* and *(Aa)ugust*?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Job - /dʒəʊb/, job = /dʒɒb/.  August (the month or proper name) = /ˈɔːɡəst/, august = /ɔːˈɡʌst/.  Leastaways, these are the way I say them (and the OED).

Comment: @Dan  OK, I didn't know about the *august* pronunciation. But *Job* and *job* I have always pronounced the same. I had to look up *Natal*.

Comment: It would be nice to add the pronunciations next to each of the words. I don't know how you'd do it without breaking up the quotation, though.

Comment: I was thinking of Steve Jobs, and that Job was a variation of the same surname. Instead it's the prophet Job, which is pronounced as if it were written "Jobe". Now, I get it. Duh!

Comment: @sumelic I wish I could do so. Thing is, the screen on my iPad keeps going black as I change tabs, to such an extent I can't keep the EDiT view active very long... :-/

Comment: Technically it's spelled SEAT. I vaguely recall that it used to be Seàt or something but I might be imagining it.

Comment: @OrangeDog Fixed. :)

Comment: I really like your last one: tangier and Tangier. That reminds me: An interesting twist on this is the way some city names are pronounced differently in different locations. (Some good examples are in [this list](http://mentalfloss.com/article/50967/20-towns-named-other-towns-pronounced-differently)). As for there being 12, more could be added at any time. Nothing prevents someone from forming a company name from a random word and changing the pronunciation. I might elect to call my new company Horse, for example, and insist on it being pronounced as "hor-SAY".

Comment: You can add to the list hockey star Mark Messier and the adjective messier.  Not to mention the tennis play Guy Forget.

Comment: Isn't it the case with all of these (except Polish/polish) that the capitalised version is pronounced differently as it is a name (almost always in another language), and so has taken the pronunciation of the other language (or an archaic form of the same)? "Nice" the place in France, is not an example of a word in the [English language](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=Nice&_searchBtn=Search). Polish/polish is the only case where neither  is a proper noun, and I don't know anyone who'd pronounce August and august differently (Except @Dan, clearly! Must be an accent thing).

Comment: I think you need to exclude names -- of people and places -- since name pronunciation is really at the discretion of the person or the country involved.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No, it isn't.  "Japan," "China," "Cologne," "Bombay," "Canton," "Spain," and many other place names are not "at the discretion of the country involved," and those are just obvious examples.  And of course anything pronounced differently "when capitalized" is a proper noun, which means all of them are going to be personal or place names.

Comment: Also *mobile* and *Mobile* (Alabama).

Comment: This is really cool, I joined this site just to upvote it

Comment: @PeterShor: But only when you mean *mobile* the adjective; *mobile* the noun is pronounced like the city.

Comment: The letters s-c-o-n-e have three pronunciations, two which relate to the foodstuff and one which relates to a place.

Comment: Oops, was supposed to continue...The foodstuff can rhyme with 'stone' or with 'gone'. I think that difference is regional and possible also class-based (but wouldn't care to say which way round). The placename is derived from the Gaelic Sgàin (which may mean "cleft") and is pronounced 'Scoon'. The point being that many of the proper Nouns in the list are derived from other languages, and like the OP can be seen as more about pronunciation of loanwords than differing pronunciation of English words?

Answer (score 18):

**[Capitonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym)**

> A capitonym is a word that **changes its meaning** (and sometimes pronunciation) **when it is capitalized**; the capitalization usually applies due to one form being a proper noun or eponym.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitonym) It is a portmanteau of the word capital with the suffix -onym. A capitonym is a form of homograph and – when the two forms are pronounced differently – also of heteronym.

The following words are **also** pronounced differently.

```
Bologna: A city in Italy    bologna: a processed meat 
Ares: god of war            ares: plural of are, a metric unit of area
August: the eighth          august: majestic or venerable
        month of the year
```

> A **heteronym** (also known as a heterophone) **is a word that is written identically but has a different pronunciation and meaning**. In other words, they are homographs that are not homophones. Thus, *row* (propel with oars) and *row* (argument) are heteronyms, but *mean* (intend) and *mean* (average) are not (since they are pronounced the same). Heteronym pronunciation may vary in vowel realisation, in stress pattern (see also Initial-stress-derived noun), or in other ways:

A few examples taken from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_(linguistics)) page:

1. They were too **close** to the door to **close** it.
2. Don't **desert** me here in the **desert**!
3. When shot at, the **dove dove** into the bushes.
4. We must **polish** the **Polish** furniture.
5. Upon seeing the **tear** in the painting I shed a **tear**.

The term *English* is similar to *Polish* in that it too can be spelled with or without a capital letter, but it is not a heteronym because its pronunciation remains identical. When a word differs in meaning, but its pronunciation doesn't change, it is called a **[homophone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homophone)**

- The **English** billiard player put more **english** on the ball

> English
>   **5.** also [english](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/English)
>   a. The spin given to a propelled ball by striking it on one side or releasing it with a sharp twist.
>   b. Bodily movement in an effort to influence the movement of a propelled object; body English.

Anther example is *Pole* (a Polish person) *pole* (another name for rod) and the verb *to pole*

- The **Pole** used a **pole** in order to **pole** upstream.

Comment: I (non-native English speaker) never realized the "s" in the verb "close" should be pronounced differently than the "s" in the noun "close". But for some reason, the "s" in the word "closer" is obviously different from the "s" in the word "closing". Good to have learned something here.

Comment: You could add an archaic unit of length to the last example: "_The **Pole** used a **pole** to **pole** a **pole** upstream_" (not a very long journey: 5 1/2 yards)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A : Although, according to the link, a "capitonym" isn't necessarily a homograph, it does say that capitonyms include both heteronyms and homographs.  Nevertheless, I love this answer.  I'd never heard of a "capitonym."

Comment: @Pakk: "closer" can be pronounced both ways. "closer" as in more close, and "closer" as in one who closes.

Comment: There is also refuse (verb) and refuse (noun meaning trash)

Comment: @Pakk: Actually, the noun “close” and the verb “close” are pronounced exactly the same — with a ‘Z’ sound, rhyming with “hose”, “nose”, “pose”, “rose”, “foes”, “goes”, “toes”, “doze”, and others.  It’s the *adjective* “close” (the antonym of “distant”) that rhymes with “dose”, and features the ‘OS’ sound that occurs in “coast” and “host”.  As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams points out, there are versions of “closer” associated with (and sounding like) both versions of “close”.

Comment: @Scott: Yes. Where I wrote 'noun', I meant 'adjective'. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: And I think I know why for me the adjective and verb sound the same: in my native language (Dutch), we never have a 'Z' sound at the end of a word. If this would occur, we say and write a 'S'. Example: plural houses is 'huizen', but singular house is not 'huiz', but 'huis'. I guess this is so fixed into my brain that I even hear a 'S' sound when a 'Z' is spoken at the end of a word.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, such a word is called a "[homograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph)."  Aside from "Polish" and "polish," another exemplar homograph is "wind" (blowing air) and "wind" (what you do to watch).

If you are looking for another word where the initial capital letter is the all-important factor, then consider:

***Moped*** (motorized bicycle by Honda)

and

***moped*** (preterit tense of the verb "to mope")

Before it became a common noun, the proper noun "Moped" was a portmanteau formed by Honda to market its motorized bicycle.

Any such initial capital letter difference is going to have to involve a word that is considered proper like this, like Polish.

Comment: +1). Are there only two in English?

Comment: No, heterographs, on the contrary, are the words that are spelled differently but pronounced the same, like ewe - you. What you meant, Benjamin, are homographs, and there are hundreds of them, not just of the type sow (plant) - sow (pig), but a much more numerous category of

Comment: @slava bakis : Sorry for the brain spaz.  I was thinking homograph but wrote heterograph.  Maybe I'm homophobic.  Just kidding.  ;-)  At any rate, I corrected my answer.  Hopefully the link, which explains both terms, helped lead you to this word that you were looking for.

Comment: @Rathony : Thanks for the +1.  There are a lot more than two: lead (the metal) and lead (the verb: to direct); affect (the verb: to influence) and affect (a set of mannerisms); pervert (the verb: to affect with deviance) and pervert (a person who is sexually perverted, sexually immoral).  Those are just off the top of my head.  I imagine there are hundreds, maybe thousands.

Comment: Why not include those words in the answer. You will be able to receive more upvotes. :-)

Comment: The two "wind" examples do not differ by initial capitalisation as required by the questioner.

Comment: @Rathony - One can easily find entire [lists](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=list+of+heteronyms) of these words on the web – though, as abligh has pointed out, this question is asking for a very specific subset.

Comment: @J.R. - Mari-Lou A gives an excellent response with "capitonym."  I'd never heard that word.  Although, it doesn't specifically address homographs, the resource provided explicitly states that a "capitonym" includes heteronyms and homographs.

Comment: "moped" the vehicle is not a trademark AFAIK, and is certainly used, lower-case, in common media.

Answer (score 3):

There is no generalized rule in English about capital letters changing pronunciation.  What you have observed are incidental cases where a capital letter allows you to distinguish between a proper noun (or derivative) and another word with a different meaning and/or pronunciation (and typically origin) that happens to have the same spelling.

Comment: As in my "_Polish the ornament_" example ... it has a capital letter but is pronounced differently than "_Polish is a language_".

Answer (score 0):

Inquisitive words are sometimes pronounced differently.  "Where is the post office?" vs. "The keys were right where I left them."

Comment: Do you mean interrogative words?  Or just *where*?  *Where* is often aspirated and *were* never is, so this isn't a clean example.